WebSockets in Next.js 14
The questions is about the WebSocket API in Next.js 14 app router. Let's assume there is a web socket server written in C# or something, so it just works. The client part is challenging. I can easily connect to a socket server in useEffect in one line using the WebSocket API, send a message, all works.
The problem is that I want to open the connection in layout.tsx and keep it for as long as layout.tsx is alive, i.e. the life of the whole application. That simply does not work, as when I navigate to some component the socket connection gets implicitly closed, for some reason.
This is all client-side components.
Things I tried:

Checked that layout.tsx or any other component are not unmounting, in which case it could drop the web socket connection, and they are not.
Moved creating the websocket connection in a separate module, implemented as singleton in WebSocketService.ts. Does not work, no matter what I do the singleton will re-create as I route from component to component, and then it creates the new websocket connection in each component, which is not what I want.
Created WebSocketProvider.tsx that uses context to keep one instance of the WebSocketService.ts only, and then wrapped all code in layout.tsx with , same thing, created new instance of WebSocketService.ts for every componet.
Used global module variable to make sure only one instance is created, it does not work.
Used ref to make sure one instance is created, does not work either.
Checked many articles and blogs, they all just use different libraries, connect to a server from one component, send a message and that's it. That's super easy, and not helping at all.

So, I am out of the ideas. I also killed the strict mode to make sure that the functions are not called twice, but it did not help. I know, everybody says it is not a good idea, but I don't trust in strict mode. Have never seen C, C++, C#, Rust or any other serious language telling "hey, let's enter functions twice, it's a great idea".
The Next.js team always creates problems, like that one, and then "use strict mode, it is great, it will help you discover issues early", but I don't believe that. Same thing with that huge issue with caching, they made a chaos and then gave 10 hacks to "easier live with this", but no solution on how to turn it off, which was not suppose to be there in the first place. Saying all this because I suspect that it is yet another issue with Next.js team, as I suspect the way they package and serve the file in dev mode might got something to do with why websocket connection and singletons are created again and again for every component, and I cannot keep one instance of those for the lifetime of the application, but I do not know enough about how it works internally.
Thank you.
